# MS PowerPoint 2003 Animation won't allow selection of an animation scheme

Tags: animation, powerpoint

While editing a PowerPoint document, I select a slide with bullet points then click Slide Show - Animation Schemes.  I select the Appear and dim scheme, but the selection doesn't "stick" - the active animation scheme still shows as "No Animation".

I've verified that the "Show Without Animation" option is NOT checked.  What else would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the PowerPoint presentation file I was working on, which had been passed on to me from someone else, was originally set up using a template from a later version of PowerPoint.  Apparently, that version had settings that were not accessible in PowerPoint 2003, so it just didn't work.

Fortunately, we'll be joining the modern world of MS Office soon and won't be dealing with this kind of problem.